# Mirror traffic using DPDK

Tags: packet, dpdk, mirroring

Is there any mechanism in DPDK by which packets can be mirrored from one port to other?

I know mbuf cloning can be done.
But is there something which can be done at hardware level.

NIC: fortville (i40e)
DPDK version: 21.11.0

I have tried packet cloning.
But want to know if any other mechanism is available in DPDK.

Answer (score 0):

Mellanox NIC supports Action sample that duplicate the packets to another port with specific ratio.